# Wrap a method into a func

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, func, polly

I want to create a generic wrapper around Polly framework so that can have single implementation. In order to achieve it I have written below code

```
    private Policy GetPolicy(EType eType)
    {
        var policy = default(Polly.Policy);

        switch (eType)
        {                

            case EType.T:
                policy = Policy.Handle<SomeException>().Retry(n, x => new TimeSpan(0, 0, x));
                break;                
        }
        return policy;
    }
```

And I am using the above method in one of my wrapper methods

```
   public TOutput Execute<TOutput>(Func<TOutput> func, EType eType)
    {
        var policy = GetPolicy(eType);

        return policy.Execute(() => func());
    }
```

Now in order to consume it I have written a sample method

```
       var handleError = new HandleError();
        var connection = handleError.Execute(() => factory.CreateConnection(), ExceptionType.Transient);
```

Till above all works fine, but as soon as I start calling the same in a method which takes parameter, then it throws error as

```
     var handleError = new HandleError();
        handleError.Execute(() => channel.ExchangeDeclare(queueDetail.ExchangeName, ExchangeType.Fanout), ExceptionType.Transient);

     The type arguments for method 'HandleError.Execute<TOutput>(Func<TOutput>, ExceptionType)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

Comment: "I have tried the below method but invain" What does this mean? Any error? Unexpected behaviour? What do you expect and what do you get instead? Anyway I can´t see any use for your wrapper. There´s no advantage on providing a method via a delegate and then directly call that delegate within your `Execute`-method.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? I smell an X-Y-Problem.

Comment: @HimBromBeere - Added the error in the question

Comment: There's not enough info to give a meaningful answer. Show us what you want to do and explain why you can't do it. I for one don't see a connection between `Save` and `Execute`.

Comment: @Fildor - added in the bottom of the question

Comment: Just pass function together with parameters there: `Execute(() => repo.Save(userId, emailAddress))`

Comment: @Evk - Have updated the question and have tried to use the way you said, it's not working.

Comment: Then please include how exactly you call it so that it's not working. Maybe your `repo.Save` doesn't have return value (void method)?

Comment: @Developer What is the return type of `channel.ExchangeDeclare(queueDetail.ExchangeName, ExchangeType.Fanout)`

Comment: @EvanHuang - Void

Comment: @Developer That's it, you need to return a value for Func<TOutput>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two `Execute` overloads, one for functions that return value and another for those which do not:

```
public TOutput Execute<TOutput>(Func<TOutput> func, ExceptionType exceptionType)
{
    var policy = GetPolicyFromExceptionType(exceptionType);
    return policy.Execute(func);
}

public void Execute(Action action, ExceptionType exceptionType)
{
    var policy = GetPolicyFromExceptionType(exceptionType);
    policy.Execute(action);
}
```

Then you can pass anything there, including functions with parameters:

```
// calls first overload
Execute(() => ImReturningValue(parameter1));
// calls second
Execute(() => IDoNot(parameter1));
```

`Policy.Execute` method also has the same overloads (one for Func, one for Action) - so you will have no problems to pass either one to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the async version:

```
public async Task<TOutput> Retry<TOutput>(Func<Task<TOutput>> func, ExceptionType exceptionType)
{
     var policy = GetPolicyFromExceptionType(exceptionType);
     return await policy.ExecuteAsync(func);
}

public async Task Retry(Func<Task> action, ExceptionType exceptionType)
{
     var policy = GetPolicyFromExceptionType(exceptionType);
     await policy.ExecuteAsync(action);
}
```